# How do I replace a Hyperlink in a Gridview Column with an image, depending on the text in the column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview, hyperlink

Question pretty much says it all. On my aspx page I have a GridView and under Columns I have  a bunch of BoundFields, one of which is a TemplateField

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID = "HyperLink1" runat = "server" Target = "_blank"
                    NavigateUrl = '<%# Eval("URL") %>'
                    Text = '<%#Eval("Status") %>'>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now, I want this Hyperlink to map to a different image, depending on what the text is evaluated to. For example, 'Success' displays a big ol' smiley face instead, 'Failed' displays a frowney face, and so on. How can I achieve this?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I should add, this is my first column, so in the RowDataBound method, I would be manipulating e.Row.Cells[0]

Answer (score 2):

You can put an image in the hyperlink like

```
<img src='/images/status/<%#Eval("Status") %>.jpg' />
```

and just make a different image for each status by name. Otherwise you'll probably have to do something on the DataBind event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
protected void myGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HyperLink HyperLink1 = e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1");
        if(SomeText == "Success")
          HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Url to Smiley";
        else
          HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Url to Frowney";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't let me change the image though. And also, I don't know what the URL is, since it's different for each row

Answer (score 0):

```
HyperLink HyperLink1 = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1");

    switch (HyperLink1.Text)
        {
             case "Completed":
                  HyperLink1.ImageUrl = "Images\\Success.png";
                  HyperLink1.ToolTip = "Completed";
```

etc

The ToolTip property maps to the alternate text for the image.

Thanks to codingbiz for getting me started.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the ImageUrl property I suggest using the `RowDataBound` event.  The handler method could would look something like:

```
protected void questionsGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataSourceDataType row;
    HyperLink hyperLink1;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow & e.Row.DataItem is DataSourceDataType)
    {
        row = (DataSourceDataType)e.Row.DataItem;
        hyperLink1 = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink1");

        hyperLink1.ImageUrl = (row.IsSuccess) ? "~/images/success.png" : "~/images/failure.png";
    }
}
```

Another trick I have used is altering the data object you are binding to to have a property which indicates the URL to use:

```
partial class DataSourceDataType
{
    public string SuccessImgURL
    {
        get
        {
            return (IsSuccess) ? "~/images/success.png" : "~/images/failure.png";
        }
    }
}
```

Then you bind to that property.

Note: `IsSuccess` would need to be replaced with your own field name or boolean condition.
I often use this with LINQ to SQL objects, so adding properties can be done in a separate file using partial classes.  This way you do not have to worry about the LINQ to SQL tools removing your additions.